# Select or subset variables whose column sums are not zero

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select or subset variables in a data frame whose column sum is not zero but also *keeping other factor variables* as well. It should be fairly simple but I cannot figure out how to run the `select_if()` function on a subset of variables using `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d"),
  B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  C = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2),
  D = c(0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5)
)

require(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select_if(funs(sum(.) > 0))

#Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
#  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Then I tried to only select `B, C, D` and this works, but I won't have variable `A`:

```
df %>% 
  select(-A) %>% 
  select_if(funs(sum(.) > 0)) -> df2
df2
#  C D
#1 3 0
#2 0 3
#3 0 2
#4 1 1
#5 1 4
#6 2 5
```

I could simply do `cbind(A = df$A, df2)` but since I have a dataset with 3000 rows and 200 columns, I am afraid this could introduce errors (if values sort differently for example).

Trying to subset variables `B, C, D` in the `sum()` function doesn't work either:

```
df %>% 
  select_if(funs(sum(names(.[2:4])) > 0))
#data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
df %>% select_if(~ !is.numeric(.) || sum(.) != 0)
#   A C D
# 1 a 3 0
# 2 a 0 3
# 3 b 0 2
# 4 c 1 1
# 5 c 1 4
# 6 d 2 5
```

The rationale is that for `||` if the left-side is `TRUE`, the right-side won't be evaluated.

Note:

- the second argument for `select_if` should be a function name or formula (lambda function). the `~` is necessary to tell `select_if` that `!is.numeric(.) || sum(.) != 0` should be converted to a function.
- As commented below by @zx8754, `is.factor(.)`should be used if one only wants to keep `factor` columns.

---

Edit: **a base R solution**

```
cols <- c('B', 'C', 'D')
cols.to.keep <- cols[colSums(df[cols]) != 0]
df[!names(df) %in% cols || names(df) %in% cols.to.keep]
```

Comment: I think they want to check if factor, maybe: `df %>% select_if(~ is.factor(.) || sum(.) != 0)` ?

Comment: Could you explain, why `~` ?

Comment: @zx8754, I guess the factor columns are due to default behavior of `data.frame` but not created on purpose. Using `!is.numeric(.)` would be more general since it also works for character columns.

Comment: Thanks, agree it is more general, just wanted to note for future readers wishing to keep factors only.

Comment: @zx8754, good point. I will edit it to reflect this and also explain the `~`.

Comment: That's great and what I needed! But is there also a way to specify the variable names specifically over which the `sum()` function is applied (e.g. `"B","C","D"`)?

Comment: @Stefan, sorry, I could think of a nice way to do it with `dplyr`. However you can always do it with base R. Remember that `dplyr` is an option but not a necessity.

Comment: Thank you @mt1022! If you can think of a nice way doing this in base R would you mind adding this to your answer as an alternative for other readers?

Comment: @Stefan, I missed a "not" after "could" in my last comment. and a base R solution added.

Comment: Thanks, that's great @mt1022!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an update for everyone who wants to use the new `dplyr 1.0.0` which doesn't have the scoped variants (like `select_if` as nicely shown by @mt1022 but deprecated):

```
df %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  select(where(~sum(.) != 0))
```

If you want to compress the two select statements into one, you cannot do this by the element-wise `&` but longer form `&&` because this produces the required boolean output:

```
df %>% select(where(~ is.numeric(.x) && sum(.x) !=0 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a soltion using data.table

```
df<-data.table(
  A = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d"),
  B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  C = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2),
  D = c(0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5)
)

df2<-df[,lapply(X = .SD,FUN = function(x){sum(as.numeric(x))}),.SDcols = colnames(df)]
df[,which(is.na(df[1,]) == F),with = F]
```

Comment: It’s good practice to denote data tables as `DT` or `dt` as they are not **d**ata**f**rames.

Comment: +1 Didn’t want to sound condescending. Just remember how puzzled I was when starting out. Some results were called tibbles, some had `1, 2, 3, ...` as row numbers and others `1:, 2:, 3:, ...`. Confused the hell out of me.

Comment: @Roman I agree though that you shouldn't name your data `df` as this is the name of a function. (There was question once where this caused some problems but I couldn't find it.)